# Regular Expression to find valid words in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text

I need to write a function `get_specified_words(filename)` to get a list of lowercase words from a text file. All of the following conditions must be applied:

- Include all lower-case character sequences including those that
  contain a `-` or `'` character and those that end with a `'`
  character.
- Exclude words that end with a `-`.
- The function must only process lines between the start and end marker lines
- Use this regular expression to extract the words from each relevant line of a file:  `valid_line_words = re.findall("[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", line)`
- Ensure that the line string is lower case before using the regular expression.
- Use the optional encoding parameter when opening files for reading. That is your open file call should look like open(filename, encoding='utf-8'). This will be especially helpful if your operating system doesn't set Python's default encoding to UTF-8.

The sample text file `testing.txt` contains this:

```
That are after the start and should be dumped.
So should that

and that
and yes, that
*** START OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***
Toby's code was rather "interesting", it had the following issues: short,
meaningless identifiers such as n1 and n; deep, complicated nesting;   
a doc-string drought; very long, rambling and unfocused functions; not 
enough spacing between functions; inconsistent spacing before and 
after operators, just like   this      here. Boy was he going to get a low
style mark.... Let's hope he asks his friend Bob to help him bring his code
up to an acceptable level.
*** END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***
This is after the end and should be ignored too.

Have a nice day.
```

Here's my code:

```
import re

def stripped_lines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        stripped_line = line.rstrip('\n')
        yield stripped_line

def lines_from_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rt') as flines:
        for line in stripped_lines(flines):
            yield line

def is_marker_line(line, start='***', end='***'):
    min_len = len(start) + len(end)
    if len(line) < min_len:
        return False
    return line.startswith(start) and line.endswith(end)


def advance_past_next_marker(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if is_marker_line(line):
            break


def lines_before_next_marker(lines):
    valid_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        if is_marker_line(line):
            break
         valid_lines.append(re.findall("[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", line))
    for content_line in valid_lines:
        yield content_line


def lines_between_markers(lines):
    it = iter(lines)
    advance_past_next_marker(it)
    for line in lines_before_next_marker(it):
        yield line


def words(lines):
    text = '\n'.join(lines).lower().split()
    return text

def get_valid_words(fname):
    return words(lines_between_markers(lines_from_file(fname)))

# This must be executed
filename = "valid.txt"
all_words = get_valid_words(filename)
print(filename, "loaded ok.")
print("{} valid words found.".format(len(all_words)))
print("word list:")
print("\n".join(all_words))
```

Here's my output:

```
 File "C:/Users/jj.py", line 45, in <module>
text = '\n'.join(lines).lower().split()
builtins.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

Here's the expected output:

```
valid.txt loaded ok.
73 valid words found.
word list:
toby's
code
was
rather
interesting
it
had
the
following
issues
short
meaningless
identifiers
such
as
n
and
n
deep
complicated
nesting
a
doc-string
drought
very
long
rambling
and
unfocused
functions
not
enough
spacing
between
functions
inconsistent
spacing
before
and
after
operators
just
like
this
here
boy
was
he
going
to
get
a
low
style
mark
let's
hope
he
asks
his
friend
bob
to
help
him
bring
his
code
up
to
an
acceptable
level
```

I need help with getting my code to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get correct output if you print each item without joining? (Asking because *that* seems to be the problem, not the whole regex title/introduction/explanation.)

Comment: The output  test code is mandatory. I can only modify the functions.

Comment: Are you referring to the word(lines) function?

Comment: I am referring to the line that produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines_between_markers(lines_from_file(fname))
```

gives you a list of list of valid words.

So you just need to flatten it :

```
def words(lines):
    words_list = [w for line in lines for w in line]
    return words_list
```

Does the trick.

But I think that you should review the design of your program :

lines_between_markers should only yield lines between markers, but it does more. Regexp should be use on the result of this function and not inside the function.

What you didn't do :

> Ensure that the line string is lower case before using the regular expression.
>
> Use the optional encoding parameter when opening files for reading.
>   That is your open file call should look like open(filename,
>   encoding='utf-8').